# bypass service worker for a specific request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I have an react app and I am using a service worker for offline purpose, I have a custom hook, this hook sends a request to check connection. If the request return a response of 200 it mean the user is online else offline. Currently I am getting a 200 ok from service worker, but the network is off. I would like to bypass the service worker and let the request run normally. The goal is to ensure the request does not return 200 while offline

here is my hook :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useOnline = () => {
    const [online, setOnline] = useState(true);

    const checkOnline = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('/hello.png');
            
            setOnline(response.ok);
        } catch {
            setOnline(false);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const change = () => {
            setOnline(!online);
        };
        checkOnline();
        window.addEventListener('online', () => change());
        window.addEventListener('offline', () => change());
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('online', () => change());
            window.removeEventListener('offline', () => change());
        };
    }, [online]);

    return online;
};
```

I was thinking to add this in my service worker

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
     if (event.request.url.match('^.*(/hello.png/).*$')) {
                return false;
            }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, because your hook will automaticly send 200 message.
It's a violation of service worker's goal, and your code will not work